# Create new (not change) stylesheets using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stylesheet

We've got a little tool that I built where you can edit a jQuery template in one field and JSON data in another and then hit a button to see the results immediately within the browser.

I really need to expand this though so the designer can edit a full CSS stylesheet within another field and when we render the template, it will have the CSS applied to it. The idea being that once we've got good results we can take the contents of these three fields, put them in files and use them in our project.

I found the jQuery.cssRule plugin but it looks like it's basically abandoned (all the links go nowhere and there's been no development in three years). Is there something better or is it the only game in town?

Note: We're looking for something where someone types traditional CSS stylesheet data in here and that is used immediately for rendering within the page and that can be edited and changed at will with the old rules going away and new ones used in their stead. I'm not looking for something where the designer has to learn jQuery syntax and enter in individual .css("attribute", "value") type calls to jQuery.

Comment: Are you creating a JSFiddle clone maybe?

Comment: There are similarities except that the focus is on CSS, jQuery Template, and JSON data. In jsFiddle the focus is CSS, HTML, and JavaScript. I've tried to look at jsFiddle before for other reasons and it's quite a complex system. Obviously it works, but I dont' want to try and extract whatever they're using (if in fact it can be extracted).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sure, just append a `style` tag to the head:

```
$("head").append("<style>p { color: blue; }</style>");
```

See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u4pna/).

You can replace the text in a dynamically added `style` tag using something like this:

```
$("head").append("<style id='dynamicStylesheet'></style>");
$("#dynamicStylesheet").text(newStyleTextGoesHere);
```

See this in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u4pna/1/).

Comment: Really? Is it that simple? Could I just some kind of marker in the <head> that would tell me what to add (and then later replace because this is very much an iterative tool).

Comment: @John My edit might be what you want, but I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: Your edit was excellent. Here's my fork where I'm showing it with a separate piece of text (with multiple styles) that could easily have come from a textarea: http://jsfiddle.net/JohnMunsch/XH2uf/

Comment: OK, now I think that's my final edit to the jsFiddle. It makes it explicit by creating a text area, letting you edit the sample CSS in it, and hit a button to immediately change the appearance of the HTML without a refresh.

Answer (score 4):

The cleanest way to achieve this is by sandboxing your user-generated content into an `<iframe>`.  This way, changes to the CSS won't affect the *editor*.  (For example, `input { display:none; }` can't break your page.)

Just render out your HTML (including the CSS in the document's `<head>`, and write it into the `<iframe>`.

[Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/3TWDj/)

```
<iframe id="preview" src="about:blank">

var i = $('#preview')[0];
var doc = i.contentWindow || i.contentDocument;
if (doc.document) doc = doc.document;
doc.open('text/html',true);
doc.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html>...</html>');
doc.close();
```

Comment: You're absolutely right about the iframe giving you that isolation and I'm thinking of making that an option. But there's a downside to that as well because iframes don't automatically resize to the contained material.

Comment: @John: Sure it can: `i.style.height = doc.body.offsetHeight + 'px';`

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

If the user should be able to edit a whole stylesheet, not only single style attributes, then you can store the entered stylesheet in a temporary file and load it into your html document using

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="temp.css" type="text/css" />');
```

Comment: That wasn't a good solution for us because there's no server involved at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you want to write an interpreter for the css? if it is entered by hand in text, then using it later would be as simple as copy and pasting it into a css file.

so if you have a textarea on your page to type in css and want to apply those rules when you press the button, you could use something like this (only pseudocode, needs work):

```
//for each css id in the text area
$.each($('textarea[name=cssTextArea]').html().split('#'), function({
  //now get each property 
  $.each($(this).split(';'), function(){
    $(elem).css({property:value});
  });
});
```

then you could write something to go through each element that your designer typed in, and get the current css rules for it (including those that you applied using some code like the snippet above) and create a css string from that which could then be output or saved in a db. It's a pain and much faffing around with substrings but unfortunately I don't know of a faster or more efficient way.

Hope this atleast gives you some ideas